# How to set two divs with same heights in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my second div changes it height dynamically  when my first div changes without changing the second div height in `css` just with `jquery`:

This is my fiddle: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/692QF/

My `html` code:

```
<div id='box'>
   <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
<div id='in'></div>
```

My `css` code:

```
#box{
background:#0066FF;
border:1px solid blue;
width:250px;
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:10px;
padding:10px;
}
#in{
display:none;
background:#000;
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
}
p{
color:white;
}
```

MY `jquery` code:

```
$('#box').hover(function(){
$('#in').toggle();
$('#in').css({
    'width' : '250px',
    'height' : '60px',
    'border' : '1px solid blue',
    'padding' : '10px'
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this fiddle for you hope this what you want actually I didn't understand your question very well

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/692QF/1/

```
var height = $('#box').height();
var width = $('#box').width();
var border = $('#box').css('border');
var padding = $('#box').css('padding');

$('#box').hover(function(){
    $('#in').toggle();
    $('#in').css({
        'width' : width,
        'height' : height,
        'border' : border,
        'padding' : padding
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to get the height of first div then assign it to second div
so your jquery

```
$('#box').hover(function(){
    var hDiv1=$(this).height();
    $('#in').toggle();
    $('#in').height( hDiv1 ).css({
        'width' : '250px',
        'border' : '1px solid blue',
        'padding' : '10px'
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/692QF/2/)